# Problem reading line to add row in datatable using VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

this is my code. When i do debugging i have problem at line                       dtnew(0)("PANEL_ID") = a.Trim

and i have no idea how to solve this. i'm very new in vb.net. Would be great to hear opinions from expert. There is certain part of the code i alter and delete. So im sorry if its seems like not a complete code.

```vb
Dim dt As New DataTable

Try
  *
  open connection *
  oraComm.CommandText = "SELECT Panel_ID, CELL_TYPE, IV_RESULT, MODEL_CD,IV_MODE,modelname,stringlength, quantitycell, " & _ " A_CL_LT_A1, A_CL_LT_A2, A_CL_LT_B1, A_CL_LT_B2, " & _ " A_WAF_ID_1, A_WAF_ID_2, A_WAF_ID_3, A_WAF_ID_4, " & _ " B_CL_LT_A1, B_CL_LT_A2, B_CL_LT_B1, B_CL_LT_B2, " & _ " B_WAF_ID_1, B_WAF_ID_2, B_WAF_ID_3, B_WAF_ID_4, " & _ " C_CL_LT_A1, C_CL_LT_A2, C_CL_LT_B1, C_CL_LT_B2, " & _ " C_WAF_ID_1, C_WAF_ID_2, C_WAF_ID_3, C_WAF_ID_4 " & _

"FROM table1 s,table2 m " & _
  "WHERE s.areacode ='hawaii' AND m.areacode ='hawaii' AND s.panel_id = '" & Me.TextBox1.Text.Trim & "' "


ada = New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter(oraComm)
ada.Fill(ds.Tables("M_DATANEW"))
dt = ds.Tables("M_DATANEW")

Dim a, c, d, e, f As String

Dim dtnew = New DataTable()

dtnew.Columns.Add("PANEL_ID", GetType(String))
dtnew.Columns.Add("CELL_TYPE", GetType(String))
dtnew.Columns.Add("IV_RESULT", GetType(String))
dtnew.Columns.Add("IV_MODE", GetType(String))
dtnew.Columns.Add("MODEL_CD", GetType(String))

a = dt.Rows(0)("panel_id").ToString.Trim
c = dt.Rows(0)("cell_type").ToString.Trim
d = dt.Rows(0)("iv_result").ToString.Trim
e = dt.Rows(0)("iv_mode").ToString.Trim
f = dt.Rows(0)("model_cd").ToString.Trim


Dim waf_ini As String = ""

For w = 1 To CInt(dt.Rows(0)("stringlength")) + 1

For x = 1 To CInt(dt.Rows(0)("cellquantity")) + 1
If w = 1 Then
waf_ini = "A_WAF_ID"
ElseIf w = 2 Then
waf_ini = "B_WAF_ID"
ElseIf w = 3 Then
waf_ini = "C_WAF_ID"

End If

dtnew.NewRow()
dtnew(0)("PANEL_ID") = a.Trim
dtnew(0)("CELL_TYPE") = c.Trim
dtnew(0)("IV_RESULT") = d.Trim
dtnew(0)("IV_MODE") = e.Trim
dtnew(0)("MODEL_CD") = f.Trim

dtnew.Rows.Add()

Next
Next

If dt.Rows.Count < > 0 Then
GridView1.DataSource = dt
GridView1.DataBind()

Else
GridView1.DataSource = Nothing
GridView1.DataBind()
End If

Catch ex As Exception
Throw ex
Finally
  *
  close connection *
  End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Add the row with  dtnew.Rows.Add(a,c,d,e,f) instead. Where a,c,d,e,f are cells, or more precisely the data you want in them.

Comment: @CruleD still having prob.  It will throw ex when trying to execute linedtnew(0)("PANEL_ID") = a.Trim

Comment: `dtnew.NewRow()` is a function that returns a row that you then populate, then add it into the dtnew.Rows collection.

Comment: @LarsTech it keep adding new row without data (empty data), any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a new row before populating it.

```
dtnew.Rows.Add(dtnew.NewRow)
a = dtnew.Rows(0)("panel_id").ToString.Trim
c = dtnew.Rows(0)("cell_type").ToString.Trim
d = dtnew.Rows(0)("iv_result").ToString.Trim
e = dtnew.Rows(0)("iv_mode").ToString.Trim
f = dtnew.Rows(0)("model_cd").ToString.Trim
```

Comment: @FAR - This is great!